Storing multiple geometry fields in geojson?
I have a postgis table with two different geometry fields (MultiPolygon and Point) and am wondering what is the proper way to load both of these fields into geojson format?
Right now, using Django's ORM and specifying the geometry field to be the Multipolygon, I get the Point field in the properties section. In this scenario it seems like I'll have to write a custom snippet of code to parse that Point field but I imagine I'm doing this wrong and there should be a cleaner way. Of course I could make two calls to the database for both Point and MultiPolygon features and then get two geojsons or combine the features into one geojson, but that's less efficient since there's an extra db call. So the question is is there a cleaner way to do this with only a single db call? Current geojson example below:
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "name":"Lost Chicken Hill",
            "center":"SRID=4326;POINT (-142.33407907878163 63.43407781229585)",
            "pk":"8a1b2de2-7517-40a5-a40f-b1e83620ab14"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     [
                        -142.340117193021,
                        63.4403931757008
                     ],
                     [
                        -142.340051766581,
                        63.440330140493
                     ],
                     [
                        -142.339693593483,
                        63.4400042282342
                     ],
                     [
                        -142.338910623747,
                        63.4397133955665
                     ],
                     [
                        -142.338597441461,
                        63.4395970621998
                     ],
        ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}

